# HDMI to VGA Adapter says Input Not Supported (Laptop)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a decent laptop and just bought an hdmi to vga adapter so i could have 2 monitors because why not you know.

I plug the cables in on my acer LCD monitor and it says Input Not Supported, but when I go to advanced settings on windows 10 it just says that the active display resolution is 1920x1080 for both screens.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does your HDMI to VGA converter have a power connector (possibly USB)? If so, did you connect it? Also, just to make sure: It’s not a VGA to HDMI converter, right?

Answer (score 2):

With the given information, what I can recommend is try to lower the resolution or change the refresh rate (you might be having a choice between 59 Hz and 60 Hz, one of them might just work). In order to change the refresh rate:

- Go to **Settings** > **System** > **Display** > **Advanced display settings**
- Under the external monitor, choose **Display adapter properties for Display #**
- Go to the **Monitor** tab, pick a refresh rate and press **Apply**

Especially with cheap HDMI to VGA adapters, it might not always be possible to run an older display at 1080p - I even had adapters of the same kind that would struggle to display a picture at 1280x1024, but 1280x960 worked. If your monitor comes with DVI or DisplayPort, try getting a from-HDMI adapter for those, as these ports are usually way better for such use (as they already convey digital signal, unlike VGA).

Comment: this is a life saver man.

Answer (score 0):

**There would be few issues. so lets take one by one**

- Bad connection adapter - please recheck your display adapter. if it's loose connection or broken.
- Change Settings - make sure your using recommended display resolution.
- Check your display drivers - make sure your using correct display drivers or your drivers are up-to date. or go *display settings* (mouse right click) -> *advance display settings* -> *display adapter properties* and on monitor tab select proper Hz range.

**Boom now you're Fine**